# C fopen errno is not set

Tags: c, file, iar, errno

I am using IAR embedded workbench for programming. I have eval board which supports microSD memory card.
I have all the libraries and the application is working. I tried to access a file which does not exists in sd card to simulate failure and capture any file open error.

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
int IsFileExists(const char* filename) {
  errno = 0;
  FILE* fptr = fopen(filename, "r");
  printf("Error:%d %s",errno,strerror(errno))
  if (fptr != NULL) {    
    fclose(fptr);
    return 1;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

The fptr is NULL and errno is 0 always. Why the errno is not set to non-zero value?

Thanks!

Comment: You're missing `<stdio.h>`

Comment: Are you getting the correct message from `strerror(errno)`?

Comment: To extend Barmar's question: what specific output does your program produce?

Comment: It's possible, of course, that your system's `fopen` simply doesn't set `errno` on error.  Does its documentation claim that it does?  The C standard doesn't require it, as far as I can tell.

Comment: regarding: `FILE* fptr = fopen(filename, "r");`  This is a very poor idea.  Suggest using `stat(2)` to determine if a file exists.

Answer (score 0):

C99-7.19.5.3(8) says nothing about errno at fopen() return.
Some other functions are required to set errno (C99-7.19.9.3 fsetpos() for instance).
So it seems it is not required for fopen.

What OS are you using ?

Answer (score -1):

You must declare errorno as extern value.
and you have no need to set errorno as 0.
It automatically sets after run fopen function.
Refer: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_error_handling.htm

Comment: Isn't that what `#include <errno.h>` does?

Comment: Doesn't errno.h declare errno itself? Perhaps with qualifications such as thread-local. I think the advice in this article is wrong.

Comment: @Samuel D.Murphy . I tried. IAR compiler reports  Error[Pe040]: expected an identifier

Comment: `errno` is often implemented as a macro, which precludes declaring it as a variable.

Comment: The standard has the following footnote: **a program that uses errno for error checking should set it to zero before a library function call, then inspect it before a subsequent library function call.**